# Imageview changes when Image changes

Tags: image, javafx, imageview, listener

I would like to somehow attach imageview to another image and make it so that when this image changes the imageview changes too. I have a "home" controller with an avatar imageview

```
    user = ViewFactory.getInstance().getUser();

    if(user.getAvatar() != null) {
        imgPreview.setImage(user.getAvatar());
    }
```

and another "settings" controller which allows to change avatar

```
    ViewFactory.getInstance().getUser().setAvatar(new Image(avatar.getAbsolutePath()));
```

and I would like to make it so that when I change avatar in settings it also changes it in home, a kind of listener for home imageview that changes when the value in user.getAvatar() is changed, but i dont know how to archive it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the avatar in your `User` model object an `ObjectProperty<Image>` (adding appropriate get/set and property accessors);

```
ObjectProperty<Image> avatar;
```

Bind the [`image` property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#imageProperty) in the `ImageView` to it.

```
imageView.imageProperty().bind(user.avatarProperty());
```

Then, when you set the avatar image property to a new value,

```
user.setAvatar(newImage);
```

the image displayed in the image view will also change.